# jQuery TypeError: example("input#autocomplete").autocomplete is not a function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, joomla

I have tried alot to remove this error but could not get success.When i am running this script on localhost its working fine but not working on Joomla frame work.
The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<?php $viewFields=array('c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby'); ?>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  var example=jQuery.noConflict();
  var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($viewFields) ?>;
  example(document).ready(function() {
   example("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: arrayFromPHP
});
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<p><img src="<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>images/search_1.png" border="0" alt="" />
<img src="<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>images/business_2.png" border="0" alt="" />
<img src="<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>images/review_3.png" border="0" alt="" />
</p>
</center>
<input id="autocomplete" />
</body>
</html>
```

Its giving me this error:-

--

```
[08:30:24.870] Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead. @ http://50.116.97.120/~amarhost/storage/media/system/js/mootools-core.js:343
[08:30:27.853] TypeError: example("input#autocomplete").autocomplete is not a function @ http://50.116.97.120/~amarhost/storage/index.php/component/storage/?action=war&Itemid=105:210
```

Comment: Look like a file reference error. check if the script was loaded in the console section first

Comment: what version of Joomla does the framework you are trying to connect to belong?

Comment: Your code works just fine with php removed: http://jsfiddle.net/SyjZB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe noconflict clear everything that is added to jQuery. try to put noconflict just after the you load jQuery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var example=jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($viewFields) ?>;
  example(document).ready(function() {
     example("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: arrayFromPHP
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that there could be multiple jquery file included. Maybe from other included php files. Remove this inclusion and keep only at one place. Best way is to include this js file in some php file and then 
include in the required file using `include_once('jquery_include.php');`.

This will probably solve your problem. I had this same problem. This solved my problem.

Some thing like this.

jquery_include.php

```
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then include this php file in required php files.

```
    include_once('jquery_include.php');
```

Hope this help.